# Crontab not triggered at all

Tags: cron, freebsd

I have the following CRON configuration:

```
crontab -l
* * * * * curl http://x.com/script.php
```

But it just doesn't work. The command "curl http://x.com/script.php" triggered manually works 
all fine so it's obviously something wrong with CRON. What could go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, 'curl' is not in the PATH, when cron is trying to execute it. Type its absolute path, or use the PATH variable in the crontab. If that doesn't help, I would check if /usr/sbin/cron is running. If it is, also check permissions of /var/cron/tabs/ and its contents, and check the log file /var/log/cron for any suscpicious errors.

Comment: Yup, specifying the absolute path to curl fixed the problem.